# Missing Events in Google Analytics triggers Towards Cloud Functions (1st Gen)

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

We have deployed [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/analytics-events) functionality in our firebase ecosystem. The events are marked for conversion & we see that setup is working. However, we have noticed that post reconciliation of the events real time events (from Cloud Trigger) vis-a-vis BigQuery - the numbers dont seem to match. We understand the feature itself is in preview - but seems we are missing 1/3 events when it comes to real time triggers.

We have done extensive investigation into the Cloud Function Logs & there are indeed missing ga_session_id's which are logged to bigquery but never hit the cloud function itself.

Did anyone face this issue ?